# Mongoose.create() and Mongoose.save() not working while new Instance () is

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to create new user accounts with mongoose.
I've previously been able to use the `create()`as well as the `var instance = new Instance () -> instance.save()` methods.

The callback for `instance.save(callback)` returns undefined while `create(callback)` returns an empty array.

Create:

```
 User.create({username: username, password: password}, (err, user) => {
    if(user) {
        console.log('user=', user)
    }
});
```

Save:

```
newUser.save(function(err, user){
      console.log('user=', user)
  })
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you post an example of the callback please ?

Comment: @Taki yes posted

Comment: Could you add the contents of err, e.g. the result of logging it? If user is null within a save callback, the err should be populated.

Comment: The params in the callback function in "save", contains only err - and not (err, user)